# what is wrong with my code? it gives an empty graph

Tags: plotting, physics

[image]

this is my code: and it gives me an empty graph?

```
\[Tau] = rc;
q = cv (1 - Exp[-t/\[Tau]])
c = 10^(-6); v = 1;
q1 = q /. r -> 1*10^3;
q2 = q /. r -> 2*10^3;
q3 = q /. r -> 5*10^3;
Plot[{q1, q2, q3}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: spaces are important. change `rc` to `r*c` and `cv` to `c*v` then it will work.

Comment: @Nasser it didn't work too

Comment: Yes it works. But the HW says to plot up to 5 ms, not 5 seconds. That is why after fixing the spaces it does not show clearly. Try `Plot[{q1, q2, q3}, {t, 0, 0.005}]` instead.  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXK7b.png)

Comment: @Nasser yes now it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define c; remove spaces in `cv` and `rc`. Use the right scaling for time `t`.

```
\[Tau] = r c;
c = 1 10^-6;
q = c v (1 - Exp[-t/\[Tau]])
c = 10^(-6); v = 1;
q1 = q /. r -> 1*10^3;
q2 = q /. r -> 2*10^3;
q3 = q /. r -> 5*10^3;
Plot[{q1, q2, q3}, {t, 0, 5 10^-3}]
```

---

A more Mathematica way would be to do the following.

```
Clear[\[Tau], r, c, q, t, v]
\[Tau] = r c;
q[t_] := c v (1 - Exp[-t/ \[Tau]])

Plot[Evaluate[
  q[t] /. {v -> 1, c -> 1 10^-6, r -> #} & /@ {1 10^3, 2 10^3, 
    5 10^3}], {t, 0, 5 10^-3}
 , PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}
 , GridLines -> Automatic
 , AxesLabel -> {"t (s)", "Q[t] (C)"}
 , PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
 ]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

To reinforce the 5 $\tau$ charging time concept, you can experiment with the following:

```
Clear[\[Tau], r, c, q, t, v]

Manipulate[
 Plot[c v (1 - Exp[-t/( r c)]), {t, 0, 15 10^-3}
  , GridLines -> Automatic
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 15 10^-3}, {0, 20 10^-6}}
  , AxesLabel -> {"t (s)", "Q[t] (C)"}
  , Epilog -> {
    Thin, Black, Line[{{0, c v}, {15 10^-3, c v}}],
    Red,
    {Line[{{# r c, 0}, {# r c, 20 10^-6}}] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}}
  ],
 {{v, 2, "Voltage"}, 0.1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 , {{r, 100, "R"}, 50, 5000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 , {{c, 10^-7, "C"}, 1 10^-7, 5 10^-6, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]